# Rails Javascript issue - Uncaught ReferenceError: filterArticleToggle is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a piece of javascript code that is switching between two different views of articles.

When I load the article index page I get the following error:

***Uncaught ReferenceError: filterArticleToggle is not defined***

I don't know what I have done wrong. I'm using the same code for profile pages and it works fine:

```
filterArticleToggle = function () {
    const grid_articles_button = document.querySelector('#grid_articles')
    const list_articles_button = document.querySelector('#list_articles')
    const grid_articles_icon = document.querySelector('#grid_articles_icon')
    const list_articles_icon = document.querySelector('#list_articles_icon')
    const grid_articles_view = document.querySelector('#grid_articles_view')
    const list_articles_view = document.querySelector('#list_articles_view')

    if (grid_articles_button && list_articles_button) {
        grid_articles_button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()

            grid_articles_icon.classList.add('text-brand-blue')
            grid_articles_icon.classList.remove('text-inherit')

            list_articles_icon.classList.remove('text-brand-blue')
            list_articles_icon.classList.add('text-inherit')

            fetch("/articles/switch_view/Grid").then(function(response) {
                return "ok"
            })

            grid_articles_view.classList.value = "sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-0 flex flex-wrap"
            list_articles_view.classList.value = 'hidden'
        })

        list_articles_button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()

            grid_articles_icon.classList.remove('text-brand-blue')
            grid_articles_icon.classList.add('text-inherit')

            list_articles_icon.classList.add('text-brand-blue')
            list_articles_icon.classList.remove('text-inherit')

            fetch("/articles/switch_view/List").then(function(response) {
                return "ok"
            })

            list_articles_view.classList.value = "sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-0 flex flex-wrap"
            grid_articles_view.classList.value = 'hidden'
        })
    }
}

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    filterArticleToggle()
})

window.filterArticleToggle = filterArticleToggle
```

This is in an article.js file that is being loaded in as the article index page loads.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `filterArticleToggle = function ()` is an implicit global which is not allowed in strict mode (and is generally regarded as a bad practice. If you want to declare a named function just use a function declaration (`function filterArticleToggle() ...`) instead of a function expression. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

Comment: That did the trick. Do you want to add this as an answer rather than a comment and I will mark it correct?